# View sent message on Firebase console

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is my first time using firebase. I am integrating Firebase Cloud Message with a node.js server and an Android client. When I push the messages to the server, the response is that the message went to the firebase server successfully.

But when I go to the firebase console, I don't see my message there and also my android device does not receive the message. I am sending the messages as topics and the android device has also subscribed to the topics.

I will be glad if someone can share a link to view the messages on the server or suggest what I am missing out.

Below is a sample response:
**Message sent to Firebase for delivery, response:
{
  "name": "projects/my-project-id/messages/7660010658785245660"
}**

Below is the code that I am using to push to the server

```
let admin       =   require('firebase-admin'),   
    serviceAccount = require('the link to my service account is here'),
    fcmObj = {};


    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)       
      });

    fcmObj.sendMsg = function(){   

      let options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 *24       
      },

      message = {
        data: {
          content: 'Hello.. we are testing our api and fcm.',
          sender: 'From Server'
        },
        topic: "News"
      };

// Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
admin.messaging().send(message, options)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', JSON.stringify(response));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
}

module.exports = fcmObj;
```

Comment: Messages sent through the Firebase Cloud Messaging API are not shown in the Firebase notifications console. So the fact that you don't see them there, is working as expected. It's hard to say why your the messages sent through the API are not showing up on the device however without seeing the code and more details. You might want to try sending a message *from* the notifications console, to see if those arrives. If they do, you at least know that your Android app is correct.

Comment: When the message is sent from the notification console, it gets to the android client.

Comment: OK. So the problem is in how you send the message. Please edit your question to include the code that you use to send the message. It would probably also be helpful to see how you handle the message on Android, and specifically how you tested.

Comment: Pls see the node.js code I use to push the message. I have edited the question

Comment: So you're sending a data message, which is quite different from the notification message that the console sends. See [the documentation on the messages types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages). Do you have an `onMessageReceived` in your Android code?

Comment: Yes the android implements an onMessageReceived() listener

Comment: After a thorough work around, I have found a solution. As Frank said, Messages sent through the Firebase Cloud Message Api does not show on the Firebase notification console. Also, Firebase will show notification messages on the Android device that is connected to the Firebase Server but data messages would have to be handled by your code.

Answer (score 4):

> Below is a sample response: Message sent to Firebase for delivery, response: { "name": "projects/my-project-id/messages/7660010658785245660" }

Means that your Firebase SDK is is sending the message successfully. (i.e. credentials are configured properly and SDK is initialised successfully.)

In your code, you've defined data( payload is optional, see documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notification-messages-with-optional-data-payload), to display the notification message you need to add a notification object.

Just add following object in your `message` object and it should work then:

```
"notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    },
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. That was something I was missing out. I finally got it working.